# Does anything similar to a row matrix determinant exist?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that a matrix must be $n \times n$ in order for it to have a determinant. Is there anything within linear algebra that could be used to characterize a row matrix $1 \times n$ in a similar way that a determinant can?

**Context :** I am trying to see if there is a way I can characterize a signal (DSP) with Linear Algebra.

Comment: By "determinate" do you mean the determinant?

Comment: @Azif00 Yes I do, my bad!

Comment: Please specify whats wrong with my question before down voting.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without knowing what it is you hope to find out about your vector by using your "something like a determinant".

Comment: In what way does a determinant "characterize" a matrix? It assigns a number to it, but "take the first element" assigns a number to a vector. It's true that det nonzero means the matrix is invertible, but since invertibility makes no sense for vectors, that can't be the analogy you're seeking. Basically, it's impossible to know what you're looking for from the question you asked, because "characterize" is just too vague.

Comment: Apparently Henning and I agree, and agree about the time to express our views. ;)

Comment: Arguably, the Euclidean length of your row-vector is analogous to the determinant.

Comment: First we would need to know what you mean by saying that the usual determinant characterises a square matrix.

Comment: I think actually just the product of the elements of the vector (row matrix) might be the best choice. If it's zero, then the vector has a zero element and is 'deficient' in some way - it doesn't need all its dimensions relative to its basis. If it's nonzero, then it's 'full rank' wrt the basis elements. This is roughly analogous to singular vs. nonsingular matrices.

Answer (score 4):

Without specifying what properties exactly you want with this new "determinant", the question is effectively impossible to answer. Arguably the most important property of the usual determinant of $n\times n$ matrices is that it is multiplicative: $\det(AB)=(\det A)(\det B)$ for all $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$. It is not possible to have this property for row vectors ($1\times n$ matrices), since obviously you cannot multiply two such matrices.

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer that I thought was interesting to investigate. If we view the determinant as a function of the columns, i.e. it is a function which takes in $n$ column vectors and outputs a number
$$
   \det (k^n)^n \to k,
$$
then the determinant is uniquely identified by the following three properties.

1. It is linear in each of the columns:
   $$
       \det(v_1, \ldots, kv_i, \ldots, v_n) = k \det(v_1, \ldots, v_k, \ldots, v_n).
   $$
2. It is alternating: if we switch the positions of two columns, the result switches sign.
   $$
       \det(\ldots, v_i, \ldots, v_j, \ldots) = - \det(\ldots, v_j, \ldots, v_i, \ldots)
   $$
3. The determinant of the identity matrix is $1$.

We could try to create a function $f : (k)^n \to k$ mimicking these properties (or $f : (k^m)^n \to k$ for non-square matrices in general). Let $f$ be any function taking row vectors to numbers, with the first two properties. Then in fact $f$ is the zero function. Why? Well if any entry $v_i$ of $v$ is zero, then
$$
   f(\ldots, 0, \ldots) = f(\ldots, 2 \cdot 0, \ldots) =2f(\ldots, 0, \ldots)
$$
so $f(v) = 0$. If $n \ge 2$, then otherwise $v$ has two nonzero entries, say $v_i, v_j$. But then $v_i = cv_j$ for some $c \neq 0$, and so
$$
   f(\ldots, v_i, \ldots, v_j, \ldots) = c f(\ldots, v_j, \ldots, v_j, \ldots) = c \cdot 0 = 0 
$$
since two entries in the vector agree. So no such functions can exist.

A generalization of this argument will work for any $m < n$. The fundamental problem is that you want the determinant to tell you when you have $n$ linearly independent columns, and this is impossible if your columns are in a space of dimension less than $n$.

So the question is, what property are you hoping to capture about your row vectors? The comment by dbx proposed that you might want a function telling you whether any of the entries in your row vector are zero. The product of all the entries does this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be seen as a follow-up of C.D. answer and dbx comment. An $n\times n$ matrix $F$ with real coefficients (for the sake of simplicity) may also represent a linear endomorphism $f$ of the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Checking if the determinant is zero (or not) tells you if the columns of $F$ are linearly independent (or not), which is related to $f$ being injective (or not). In addition, since an injective linear endomorphism between vector spaces of the same dimension is automatically bijective, this tells you in fact if $f$ is an isomorphism (or not).

An $m\times n$ matrix $F$ (with $m\geq n$), in turn, represents a linear endomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. This is injective if and only if the columns of $F$ are linearly independent, if and only if the rank of $F$ is maximal, if and only if there exists a non-zero $n\times n$ [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)). In this sense, determinants can be still used to "characterize" non-square matrices.

In the particular case of your interest, that is to say, if $F$ is a $1\times n$ matrix, the minors are the entries of $F$, in coonection with what dbx said.